# How to extract strings and integers separately from a string in Java?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, indexof

I'm doing an assignment where I have to type in lines on the scanner.

Take `U8` as an example. `U` and `8` both have a meaning and, therefore, I have to split them up.

Here's what I have so far for the `U` part:

```
userInput = userInput + " ";

index = userInput.indexOf(" ");            

strA = userInput.substring(0, index);              

userInput = userInput.substring(index+1, userInput.length());
index = userInput.indexOf(" ");

userInput = userInput.substring(index+1, userInput.length());
```

Now, I just can't find out how to extract the integer separately. How can I do that?

Finally, I need to extract multiple strings and integers from one line. All string-integer pairs are separated by a space, for example: `U8 U7 ...`.

I cannot use `Split()`.

Comment: I revised your question and tried to improve your explanations in order to make your question easier to understand. I also included information from one of your comments. Next time, please use the edit button below your question to add additional information directly to the question. Please try to always describe your problem as precisely as possible. This helps readers to better understand your problem. For example, it would be good to know, why you can't use `Split()`.

Comment: @honk Sorry mate! Not very good with this site. Will try to keep that in mind. Thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going off of Paul's answer, to make this able to work for any number of char int inputs that are separated by a space, you can use:

```
    String input = "U80 G9 Q4";
    ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length() - 1; i++) {
        char letter = input.charAt(i);
        String num = "";
        for(int j=i+1;j<input.length();j++){
            i++;
            if(input.charAt(j)!=' '){
                num+=input.charAt(j);
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
        int number = Integer.parseInt(num + "");
        ints.add(number);
        chars.add(letter);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ints.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Letter: " + chars.get(i) + " Number: " + ints.get(i));
    }
```

Output:

```
Letter: U Number: 80
Letter: G Number: 9
Letter: Q Number: 4
```

Sorry for removing hints in the code, but I just had to quickly copy/paste since I have to leave soon, but I hope this helps!

Comment: My professor says its "Too easy" Wont teach us to program. And is there any way i could go about having it so if there is a 10 instead of a 1 it would recognize it was 10 not a 1?

Comment: well thats dumb, ive never heard a prof. say that, and to answer your question, do you want U10 instead of U1? and do you want there to be multiple letters aswell, or just numbers

Comment: @JonRoy I have edited the code to deal with multiple numbers

Comment: Thank you! Very much. Going to keep this code saved so i can re-read it and base some programs around it so i wont forget it. Thanks

Comment: @JonRoy Thats what stack overflow is all about, happy programming!

Comment: If i was to do this for two separate people, with two different inputs would i just change the variable names?

Comment: @Jon Roy all you have to do is make it a method that takes in String input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94505/discussion-between-jon-roy-and-kore).

Answer (score 0):

If the letter would be the first character in the String and the number the second part, you could use charAt method.

Example:

```
String input="U8";
char letter=input.charAt(0);
char number=input.charAt(1);
//convert char to int
int integer=Integer.parseInt(""+number);
System.out.println("Letter: "+letter+"    Number: "+integer);`
```

Comment: Hey thanks! Would this worth with my code already that i have? In some way, I need to have multiple Strings/int's on one line. All separated by a space U8 U7 etc?

Comment: @Jon Roy Please +1 this code if it helped you, and also I have added an answer that continues off of this code and does what you want with the spaces